# Computing definite integrals in python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, integral

I'm trying to write a loop that calculates the value of a definite integral at each step. The function `bigF` is very complicated. To put it in simple terms, it integrates a bunch of terms with respect to `s`, `from s=tn-(n/2)` to `s=tn+(n/2)`. After the integration, `bigF` still has a variable `t`. So you can say `bigF(t) = integral(f(s,t))`, where `f(s,t)` is the big mess of terms after `integrate.integ`. In the last line, I want to evaluate `bigF(t)` at `t=tn` after `bigF` computes the integral of `f(s,t)`

After running, I get the error `global name 's' is not defined`. But `s` was meant to be just a dummy variable in the integration, since I am computing a convolution. What do I need to do?

```
import numpy as np  
import scipy.integrate as integ 
import math 

nt=5001#; %since (50-0)/.01 = 5000
dt = .01#; % =H
H=.01

theta_n = np.ones(nt)
theta_n[1]=0#; %theta_o
omega_n = np.ones(nt)
omega_n[1]=-0.4# %omega_o
epsilon=10^(-6)
eta = epsilon*10
t_o=0

def bigF(t, n):
    return integrate.integ((422.11/eta)*math.exp((5*(4*((eta*t-s-tn)^2)/eta^2)-1)^(-1))*omega, s,tn-(n/2),tn+(n/2))

for n in range(1,4999)
    tn=t_o+n*dt;
    theta_n[n+1] = theta_n[n] + H*bigF(tn, n);
```

Comment: `^` in Python means XOR, not "power".  This is a serious bug in several places in your code.  `1^1` is zero, much to your surprise.

Comment: I'm guessing that you meant to pass a function to integ, not a computed value.  So you should probably put `lambda s: ` in front of your argument to integ.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a convolution, sounds like you want [numpy.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html).